# I can't get my custom GPT to accept an API key - "error saving draft"

Tags: chatgpt, openai, api

I'm trying to build a custom gpt with an action, basically the custom gpt can access an API if given proper instructions. I'm trying to get it to connect to plausible. I have built a simple code as a proof of concept. The code does not cause any error and the action is recognized:[image: action is recognized]

Of course, plausible requires an API key to authenticate. But as a first step, I test the code in the preview and ask gpt to pull some data from plausible. It tries to connect to plausible (the action is recognized), and gives me a message that an API key is required. So far so good. Then I save my key in the Authentication section, using the bearer auth (as required by plausible).

[image: I save my key in the auth section]

Then, I consistently get an "error saving draft" error message:[image]

```
    {
  "openapi": "3.1.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "Simplified Plausible Analytics API for website.com",
    "description": "Simplified API schema for accessing aggregated analytics data of website.com using Plausible Analytics API.",
    "version": "1.0.0"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "https://plausible.io"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/api/v1/stats/aggregate": {
      "get": {
        "description": "Aggregates metrics over a specified time period for website.com.",
        "operationId": "aggregateStats",
        "security": [
          {
            "bearerAuth": []
          }
        ],
        "parameters": [
          // ... (parameters remain unchanged)
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful response",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/AggregateStatsResponse"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "securitySchemes": {
      "bearerAuth": {
        "type": "http",
        "scheme": "bearer",
        "bearerFormat": "JWT"
      }
    },
    "schemas": {
      // ... (schemas remain unchanged)
    }
  }
}
```

What could be the cause of that? How can I troubleshoot this?

Here is a sample of my code (that gpt recognizes properly):

Comment: I have the same issue with OAuth. My service works as a plugin so it seems an openai bug to me.

Comment: having same problem. There's also a 500 in the network tab (POST to https://chat.openai.com/backend-api/gizmos)

Comment: same problem here, communication with an external API works properly (but returns Forbidden response) and when I try to store API Key I get internal server error in chatgpt